# Insufficient IIS actions in NOLIO

Tags: nolio

I am not able to get enough IIS actions like modify app pool directory, modify home directory etc in NOLIO. Please can anybody suggest how would these actions be available for IIS in NOLIO.however same are available for IIS6

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the run command line action as a wildcard and build your own component to extend the basic IIS7 actions. Rename the command line actions as you want, and run these commands - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc732992(v=WS.10).aspx

A more sophisticated and complex solution would be to implement your own actions using the actions SDK.

Comment: Thanks Ido, that helped me!

Comment: Can you also help me on how to use "Compare two folders" action with an example?